# Memory leak on instrument at NSString stringWithFormat

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

In my `appDelegate` I am using `LocationManager` :

```
- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    float latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
     strLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitude];
    float longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    strLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", longitude];
    [self CheckOperation];

}
```

**strLatitude** and **strLongitude** are global strings. This is absolutely fine. Even on analyzing the application I don't get any memory leak. But when I profile my application I receive a memory leak at

```
strLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitude];
```

and

```
strLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", longitude];
```

of **32 bytes**.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Hai  Nitish check below URL , i think it help for u bcoz u r string tune to synthesize and release http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/2/8/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html

Comment: @Nag: I have not created any property for both strings.

Comment: Wat i am saying same thing "Steve" said that why u r commenting else part

Comment: What is the first usage of strLatitude?. Post all assignments to strlatitude that happened before the line strLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitude];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you're seeing a leak and not simply just an allocation?

If you do actually have a leak here then there are some potential suspects:

**Are you using ARC? If not, here are some possible problems:**

- Are you releasing it in dealloc?
- If this method gets run more than once, you aren't releasing the last value before you reassign it.
- If you're not using copy semantics, and you're passing this string reference off to someone else, and they aren't properly releasing it, you'll also get a backtrack to this line.

EDIT:

(Per the comments below)

You should realize that `stringWithFormat:` is allocating a string and queuing up an autorelease on it... so you need to retain it somewhere.

I assumed you were doing this somewhere because you aren't getting an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" - but rather, supposedly, a leak.

You shouldn't be leaking an autoreleased object unless you've retained it somewhere (hence the assumption).

Given you need to be retaining it somewhere, my above suggestions are valid - each retain needs a matching release.

I do agree that you should be using properties for these strings.

It's simple to convert them - and takes care of a lot of things for you.

In your Interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * strLatitude;
```

In your Implementation:

```
@synthesize strLatitude;
```

To assign:

```
self.strLatitude = ...
```

(the "self." part is important)

And make sure you set that to nil in dealloc.

Comment: Firstly, I am not allocating or retaining the strings. So why should I dealloc them? Secondly, I did try to put them as **nil** each time but still got the leak.

Comment: @Nitish You absolutely are allocating a string. That's what stringWithFormat: does. You can't get a new string without putting it somewhere. Since it's autoreleased from that method I'm assuming you're retaining it somewhere that I can't see in the snippet. Are you using arc or not? That info will definitely help.

Comment: @Nitish - I didn't say it was - just asking whomever it was, why? They are free to submit an answer if they think they have a better idea given the relatively little amount of information - of if they think anything i've said is factually incorrect.      **You didn't answer my question though - are you using ARC or not?**

Comment: Actually I am not using ios5. So can't use ARC.

Comment: So you should realize that `stringWithFormat:` is allocating a string and queuing up an autorelease on it... so you need to retain it somewhere, which I assumed you were doing somewhere because you aren't getting an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" - but rather a leak. You shouldn't be leaking an autoreleased object unless you've retained it somewhere (hence the assumption). And, given you need to be retaining it somewhere, my above suggestions are valid - each retain needs a matching release.

Comment: - (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation *)newLocation
     fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
 
 float latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
  strLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitude];
 float longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
 strLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", longitude];
    [self CheckOperation];
    strLatitude = nil;
    strLongitude = nil;
    [strLatitude release];
    [strLongitude release];
 
}

Comment: According to you should I or should I not get the leak here?

Comment: One thing more. I am using the same thing many a times in my application. I never get a leak there.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, but this is a good answer and deserves my upvote.

Comment: @Nitish: This just can't be leaking.  Either it's a false positive, or something else is causing trouble that we don't know about.

Comment: @Nitish - I don't know what "CheckOperation" does... but I'd think you'd have no leak there - and that the `release` calls are completely pointless since you're calling `release` on `nil`. However, if you didn't set them to `nil` I'd expect you'd get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` if you attempted to use those strings later on without retaining them somewhere before they get autoreleased.

Comment: @Nitish: Regarding: `One thing more. I am using the same thing many a times in my application. I never get a leak there.` Then you're probably running on borrowed time not getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors.... it's only a matter of time before you do. NSStrings are objects just like anything else and need to be dealt with accordingly

Comment: i agree with u r answer this the correct way to alloc and release

Comment: @Nitish You don't have to target iOS 5.0 to use ARC.  You just have to use Xcode 4.2 or later and target iOS 4.0 or later.

Comment: @robmayoff: But keep in mind you cannot use `weak` references on anything lower than iOS 5.

Comment: I got the issue. Actually the issue was deep inside. I was assigning one of the properties which was originally retained.